# How to use hook_node API in Drupal 6 to fetch and display contents from Database

Tags: php, database, internationalization, drupal-6, hook

i have saved the translated contents for my D6 site inside my custom database table(my table has columns like title,body etc). My site is in English and it has the source contents of these translated ones. I need to pull from the database and display the French contents when French is selected inside the language switcher and so on. I have researched that hook_node API is a way to achieve this. Would like to have your inputs on the same. 
This is the sample screen shot of a page in my site.
[Sample Node 3 Of my site](http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-1208-12.html)
This is the screenshot of my custom database table:
[Database table](http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-1208-15.html)
If you see the row with sr-id '2', i have my spanish translation of the node 3 present in the database .
I would like to have some guidance as to how this row can be fetched and displayed on my UI as seen in the UI screenshot when the user selects 'Espanol' via hook_node API.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it using the code

```
<?phpfunction freeway_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL)  
        {
          $currLang = i18n_get_lang(); 
            switch ($op) 
            {      case 'load':    
              $node_id = $node->nid;
               $nodeSrcLang = $node->language;
             if($nodeSrcLang == en)
                {
               $nodeSrc = 'en-us';         
               }  
                  if($currLang == fr){      
                   $frewayLang = 'fr-fr'; 
                          } 
                   if($currLang == es){   
                  $frewayLang = 'es-es';    
                   } 
               $nodeId = $node->nid; 
               $result = db_query("SELECT node_title,node_body FROM {freeway}  
                WHERE node_id = '$nodeId'          
                 AND src_lang ='$nodeSrc'         
                 AND tar_lang='$frewayLang'");      
                while ($record  = db_fetch_object($result))   
             {       
               $node->body = $record->node_body;     
              $node->title = $record->node_title;    

            }              
             break;        } }?>
```